# Python3 gdal/ogr open OpenStreetMap data file always returns None

Tags: python-3.x, openstreetmap, gdal, ogr, osm.pbf

I'm using Python 3 and **gdal/ogr** module to open/read `.osm.pbf` data files downloaded from **OpenStreetMap**. With the method presented in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439205/parsing-osm-pbf-data-using-gdal-ogr-python-module), I could successfully parse open the file a week ago through the following code:

```
import gdal, ogr

gdal.SetConfigOption('OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING', 'YES')
osm_pbf = ogr.Open('file.osm.pbf')
```

However, it all happened suddenly that the same method won't work any more to the same `.osm.pbf` data file. When I try to run `osm_pbf = ogr.Open('file.osm.pbf')` now, it always returns `None`. As `osm_pbf` is always `None`, it's impossible to parse the data any further.

Does anyone know what's happening here? Your kind help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm unable to install the module right now, but I'd take a look at the code of the `ogr.Open` function and find out in which situation it returns `None`. Maybe you have moved the `file.osm.pbf` file by accident on your disk, so `ogr.Open` is unable to find it.

Comment: Thanks @GeckStar . the path to `file.osm.pbf` is correct. Look forward to your response!

Comment: I took a look at the source, but it's beyond my knowledge. The doc of the `Open` method however states: "NULL on error or if the pass name is not supported by this driver, otherwise an handle to a GDALDataset.". `NULL` here might mean `None` in Python. That's all I found out. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @GeckStar anyway for your effort.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, after trying to use gdal from a python wrapper: https://github.com/dezhin/pygdal